# How customize color Logger with sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I would like to have the debug in orange instead of red, but I don't know where configure (overload?) the default sails logger. I guess I'll do that in the bootstrap, but how? Thanks.

Btw, have twice red, one for error and one for debug doesn't seems really good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sails.log` uses [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) internally, check on the available options in the Winston docs. For 0.9.x you have to jump through some hoops I listed below.

### For Sails v0.9.8

Backport the [logger hook found in 0.10](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/lib/hooks/logger):

- Put it into **/api/hooks/logger**
- Install dependencies: `npm install --save lodash captains-log sails-util`
- See example config under "For Sails v0.10".
- Omit the definition for `silly`, there is no such log level under v0.9.8

### For Sails v0.10

Define colors in **config/log.js** (default config, taken from [here](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/master/themes/winston-light.js))

```
module.exports.log = {
  level: 'info',

  colors: {
    silly: 'rainbow',
    input: 'grey',
    verbose: 'cyan',
    prompt: 'grey',
    info: 'green',
    data: 'grey',
    help: 'cyan',
    warn: 'yellow',
    debug: 'blue',
    error: 'red'
  }
};
```

### Available log styles

Found in nodejs [color](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/blob/master/colors.js) module):

- white
- grey
- black
- blue
- cyan
- green
- magenta
- red
- yellow
- whiteBG
- greyBG
- blackBG
- blueBG
- cyanBG
- greenBG
- magentaBG
- redBG
- yellowBG